VAAPI decoding on UBUNTU does not display video
I am trying to decode and display a video using gstreamer vaapi streamed over ethernet network. I don't have any errors just the video is not displayed.
The pipeline used on sender is:
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.avi or .mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=15 ! queue ! udpsink host=239.0.0.1 port=9001 async=false

and the outcome of it is :
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...

And on receiver :
GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps = "video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true,packetsize=(int)188" address="239.0.0.1" port=9001 ! queue ! tsdemux ! queue ! vaapih264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false tried also with glimagesink , vaapisink no result.

with the outcome:
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiDecodeBin:vaapidecodebin0/GstQueue:vaapi-queue: max-size-time = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiDecodeBin:vaapidecodebin0/GstQueue:vaapi-queue: max-size-buffers = 0
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstVaapiDecodeBin:vaapidecodebin0/GstQueue:vaapi-queue: max-size-bytes = 0
Got context from element 'vaapipostproc0': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayX11\)\ gldisplayx11-0";
Got context from element 'vaapipostproc0': gst.vaapi.Display=context, gst.vaapi.Display=(GstVaapiDisplay)"\(GstVaapiDisplayGLX\)\ vaapidisplayglx0";
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue0.GstPad:src: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstTSDemux:tsdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock

Please tell me if I missed something because no video is displayed.

you probably are missing the rtp payloads before sending the packets through udpsink
try something like
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.avi or .mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=15 ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=239.0.0.1 port=9001 async=false

And then, on the receiver side:
GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps = "video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true,packetsize=(int)188" address="239.0.0.1" port=9001 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! tsdemux ! queue ! vaapih264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false


Hi , I just tried and on receiver side I am getting this WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link queue0 to rtph264depay0 but if I am exchanging places between the rthp264depay and tsdemux then I don't receive any error but no video is displayed.

If I am running with GST_DEBUG=4 I got these debugs                         GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1771:gst_element_link_pads_full: trying to link element tsdemux0:(any) to element rtph264depay0:(any)
GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstelement.c:925:gst_element_get_static_pad: no such pad 'private_%01x_%05x' in element "tsdemux0"
GST_ELEMENT_PADS gstutils.c:1225:gst_element_get_compatible_pad: Could not find a compatible pad to link to rtph264depay0:sink
default gstutils.c:2161:gst_element_link_pads_filtered: Could not link pads: tsdemux0:(null) - rtph264depay0:(null)

GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:648:gst_parse_perform_link: linking some pad of GstRtpH264Depay named rtph264depay0 to some pad of GstH264Parse named h264parse0 (0/0) with caps "(NULL)" and even if I get rid of rthp264depay the tsdemux pads will have the same problem, perhaps is something wrong with tsdemux ?

These pipelines work for me
Source -
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw ! queue ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=<receiver_ip> port=9001 async=false
Receiver -
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9001 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 ! queue ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink

Just read about the tsdemux element, its used to demux MPEG streams, and to create MPEG stream on the source side, you have to mux the h264 encoded stream into MPEG transport stream format using mpegtsmux
So, the source pipeline would look like
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.avi or .mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=15 ! mpegtsmux ! queue ! udpsink host=239.0.0.1 port=9001 async=false

And then you can demux it on receiving side
GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc caps = "video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true,packetsize=(int)188" address="239.0.0.1" port=9001 ! queue ! tsdemux ! queue ! vaapih264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false

OR you can decide you create RTP stream instead of JPEG transport stream and do this
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.avi or .mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! queue ! x264enc pass=qual quantizer=15 ! rtph264pay ! queue ! udpsink host=239.0.0.1 port=9001 async=false

Receiver side:
GST_VAAPI_ALL_DRIVERS=1 gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=9001 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96!  queue ! rtph264depay ! vaapih264dec ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink sync=false

